# ffmpeg configuration for embedded linux

Tags: ffmpeg, embedded-linux

I am trying to cross compile the ffmpeg into my embedded linux system, and I need to shrink the library size as small as possible for saving the space. What components should enable during the configuration if I just need to convert the h264 and mp4 file to flv format file? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [buildroot ffmpeg config](http://git.uclibc.org/buildroot/tree/package/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.mk)
Here you have an overview of the options you can enable or disable.

Comment: Or just run `./configure --help` to view all options.

Comment: Thank for your reply,
I've tried to see the options, but actually what I'm willing to know is what options I should turn on for converting h264/mp4 to flv.